# ggplot: plot line by adding two variables from two data frames

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a plot where the y-data is a result of combining two variables from two different data frames.  The reason for not wanting to join them and create a new data frame, is that one dataset (named rslp.514) is a fixed dataset, but I have numerous datasets (which will continue to increase) which I need to add to rslp.514 to get the final graph.

So to just plot up the varying data (without rslp.514) I have:

```
  ggplot(rsl_S1, aes(V1)) + xlim(0,22) + ylab("RSL (m)") + xlab("ka yr BP") + labs(title="RSL Big 1000 m") + theme_bw() + theme(legend.position="none") + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-140,20), breaks=seq(-140, 20, 20)) + geom_line(aes(y=V2, colour = "var0"))
```

Obvious if the 'fixed' data was in the same data frame, I'd simply edit the geom_line element to

```
  geom_line(aes(y=V2 + NA, colour = "var0"))
```

So my probably very stupid question is how to I add 'NA' from data frame rslp.514?  I have tried various options to no success.

Many thanks

Edit: sample data frame 'rsl_S1'

```
    V1       V2       V3       V4       V5       V6       V7
 1  0 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
 2  1 0.262982 0.324986 0.345488 0.332659 0.251416 0.310821
 3  2 0.126890 0.123733 0.122514 0.122677 0.122999 0.123271
 4  3 0.303262 0.308051 0.311852 0.312859 0.310860 0.312258
 5  4 0.639855 0.707493 0.732577 0.721003 0.637310 0.698469
 6  5 0.593978 0.596795 0.600730 0.602418 0.599899 0.602315
```

Sample data frame 'rslp.514'

```
   RSL            NA
1   0  0.0000000000
2   1  0.0007176804
3   2  0.0371870282
4   3 -0.1121277544
5   4 -0.3049994436
6   5 -0.7989087400
```

Comment: Can you post an example of your data set? The added complication is that you would need to specify which values get added together (which you do not need to do in the within df example you alluded to, as they are in the same row). Are you using the x value to merge them? If so, I don't think this is really suited to ggplot, but instead simply create a function wrapper than merges and then plots.

Comment: Hi - thanks for your reply.  I have edited the original post with a couple examples of the two data frames.

Comment: `NA` is a pretty terrible name for a column to use with non-standard evaluation, since `NA` is a reserved word in R.

Comment: Ok, that is a fair and helpful comment - that was just what it came out of the model code.  It can easily be changed.

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this that doesn't involve joining the data frames. Are you always supplementing your fixed dataset with one other data frame, and it's varying? Or will you add one, then another, then another cumulatively?